# Why directly mutate react state and setState({}) aftewards successfully update and renders the component without bugs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assuming i have a `Counter` component and it renders a button that you could click to increment its count:

```js
class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }

  inc = () => {
    // Directly mutate state and setState({})
    this.state.count += 1
    this.setState({})
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.inc}>{this.state.count}</button>
    )
  }
}
```

In the `inc` method, instead of doing

```js
setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }))
```

i directly mutated the state, and given an empty object to `setState` function. I clearly know this is not a recommended pattern, but just curious why this example would work and seems no bugs at all. I clicked the button and it updates the count successfully.

What do those two lines do under the hood, and Do they actually equal the official recommended way of setState?

Comment: I think this line causes the rerender `this.setState({})`. And this line `this.state.count += 1` changes the state, but it won't trigger a rerender. But this is not equal to the recommended way

Comment: Mutating directly: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bartik-y2kx6z?file=/src/App.js Standard way: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-platform-9p6mhr?file=/src/App.js Notice that in the console when mutating directly, state is synced, but in the standard way it shows the old value, as it should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why directly mutate react state and setState({}) aftewards successfully update and renders the component [...]

Calling the `setState` function asks react to rerender the component, and `this.setState({})` says to rerender and change no state values. Even though you've told react to change no values, it still renders by default, and when it does it uses whatever values happen to be in state. And since you've mutated the state, the state happens to have a new value.

> [...] without bugs?

It only seems bug free because you've got a simple example. The bugs will show up when you need to do anything with the previous state. For example, if you add in a `shouldComponentUpdate`, the previous state will always equal the current state:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.log(prevState.count, this.state.count);
  return prevState.count !== this.state.count;
}
```

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-phoebe-pdqml2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: "*Even though you've told react to change no values, it still renders by default*" - is that guaranteed or may they optimise this away? Does it maybe happen only in dev mode?

Comment: @Bergi i'm not sure. My guess would be that it happens both in dev and prod, and that it is guaranteed in current versions of react (with the assumption that `shouldComponentUpdate` and `PureComponent` are not being used, which is what i meant by "by default")

Comment: Also, `useState` behaves differently, so i'm only referring to `this.setState` in class components

Comment: Ah, right, `setState` never had the behaviour to avoid re-rendering if the value was the same, you had to be explicit in `shouldComponentUpdate` for that - and I doubt this will ever change since class components are unlikely to see new features